# vb.net .ToArray() Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, opennlp

I am building a string and I know this is a long shot for an answer; but just wondering why I am getting an 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' at this code 'parsedSentences.ToArray()'...

```
_coreferenceFinder.GetCoreferenceParse(parsedSentences.ToArray())
```

I am converting c# to vb.net to test the coref model in opennlp and it works in the c# project but the conversion to vb.net has failed me somehow.

Hope someone can shed some light on this.

```
Private _sentenceDetector As MaximumEntropySentenceDetector
Private _tokenizer As AbstractTokenizer
Private _posTagger As EnglishMaximumEntropyPosTagger
Private _chunker As EnglishTreebankChunker
Private _parser As EnglishTreebankParser
Private _nameFinder As EnglishNameFinder


Private _modelPath As String = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\Resources\Models\"

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim output = New StringBuilder()

    Dim sentences As String() = SplitSentences("Colonoscopy done on 23.05.12 at Apollo Hospitals revealed entire colonic mucosa studded with polyps of varying sizes ranging from few mm to 2-3cms most of which are pedunculated , morein rectum than proximally. Biopsy taken - ? adenomatous polyposis. caseno sugessted")

    Dim _coreferenceFinder As TreebankLinker = New TreebankLinker(_modelPath + "coref")

    Dim curDir As String = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("") ' Environment.CurrentDirectory

    For Each sentence As String In sentences
        Dim tokens As String() = TokenizeSentence(sentence)
        Dim tags As String() = PosTagTokens(tokens)

        Dim posTaggedSentence As String = String.Empty

        For currentTag As Integer = 0 To tags.Length - 1
            posTaggedSentence += tokens(currentTag) + "/" + tags(currentTag) + " "
        Next

        output.Append(posTaggedSentence)
        output.Append(vbCr & vbLf)

        Dim parsedSentences = New List(Of Parse)()
        Dim sentenceParse As Parse = ParseSentence(sentence)
        parsedSentences.Add(sentenceParse)

        output.Append(vbCr & vbLf & vbCr & vbLf)

        If _coreferenceFinder Is Nothing Then
            _coreferenceFinder = New TreebankLinker(_modelPath + "coref")
        End If

        output.Append("error appears here...")
        output.Append(_coreferenceFinder.GetCoreferenceParse(parsedSentences.ToArray()))
        output.Append(vbCr & vbLf & vbCr & vbLf)
    Next

    Response.Write(output.ToString())

End Sub
```

And here is the stack trace...

```
Source Error: 


Line 61: 
Line 62:             output.Append("error appears here...")
Line 63:             output.Append(_coreferenceFinder.GetCoreferenceParse(parsedSentences.ToArray()))
Line 64:             output.Append(vbCr & vbLf & vbCr & vbLf)
Line 65:         Next

Source File: D:\Sites\Coref\Default.aspx.vb    Line: 63 

Stack Trace: 


[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   OpenNLP.Tools.Coreference.Similarity.Context.GetLemmas(Context context) +95
   OpenNLP.Tools.Coreference.Similarity.Context.GetSynsetSet(Context context) +121
   OpenNLP.Tools.Coreference.Similarity.Context.Initialize(IHeadFinder headFinder) +340
   OpenNLP.Tools.Coreference.Similarity.Context..ctor(Span span, Span headSpan, Int32 entityId, IParse parse, String extentType, String nameType, IHeadFinder headFinder) +64
   OpenNLP.Tools.Coreference.Mention.MentionContext..ctor(Span span, Span headSpan, Int32 entityId, IParse parse, String extentType, String nameType, Int32 mentionIndex, Int32 mentionsInSentence, Int32 mentionIndexInDocument, Int32 sentenceIndex, IHeadFinder headFinder) +78
   OpenNLP.Tools.Coreference.Mention.MentionContext..ctor(Mention mention, Int32 mentionIndexInSentence, Int32 mentionsInSentence, Int32 mentionIndexInDocument, Int32 sentenceIndex, IHeadFinder headFinder) +174
   OpenNLP.Tools.Coreference.AbstractLinker.ConstructMentionContexts(Mention[] mentions) +608
   OpenNLP.Tools.Coreference.AbstractLinker.GetEntitiesFromMentions(Mention[] mentions) +68
   OpenNLP.Tools.Lang.English.TreebankLinker.GetCoreferenceParse(Parse[] parsedSentences) +818
   _Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Sites\Coref\Default.aspx.vb:63
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +95
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +59
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2952
```

Comment: From that stack trace, it appears that something has not been set inside your `TreebankLinker` object that is required in order for the call to `GetCoreferenceParse` to succeed.  As you can see, the exception occurs several calls within that.  You might need to consult the documentation for that component.

Comment: I can't seem to find any documentation on the internet to explain what this does 'Dim parsedSentences = New List(Of Parse)()' I believe its the ref to parsedSentences that is not working, because in the c# project it works perfectly.  I just need to understand this line above.  Can you help?

Comment: Why would you need documentation for that? It declares the variable `parsedSentences`, creates a new `List(Of Parse)` object and assigns it to the variable. Are you, perhaps, implying that you don't know what the `Parse` type is? If so then you're not alone. I don't think that it's part of the .NET Framework so it's presumably from that OpenNLP library.